# Could we add a tooltip to the Stack Exchange site links in footer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, footer

When hovering over the footer links for the other SE sites, could the `title` be used to display the name for the site.

When hovering over cooking for example, it could popup with "Seasoned Advice".

Could be useful for people who know the site by that name and not its SE name (or the reverse depending on how you interpret what I just wrote)...

Comment: Good suggestion, wonder why it didn't get any attention

Answer (score 8):

I just thought of something very much like this as part of [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101688/would-it-be-useful-to-link-the-other-stack-exchange-sites-from-each-other/101690#101690) to a very similar question.

In my case I suggested using the tag line as seen in the Multi-Collider:

[image: multi-collider]

as that gives more information about what the site is about.

Comment: I think the tag line would convey more meaning than the site name -- e.g.  Stats = "Cross Validated" = "Q&A for statisticians, data analysts, data miners, and data visualization experts".

Answer (score 1):

With the new footer that is rolling out over the next couple of days, we will have clarification in parentheses for site names that are unclear.   And tooltips.

Comment: Capitalizing the Tooltip would be nice. And should we make a meta post for our site if we want the tooltip to change?