# Would it be useful to link the other Stack Exchange sites from each other?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I'm not a very regular poster on Stack Overflow, but (I think) I've been using it before it became Stack Exchange. I'm a developer, so I only use SO to gain input from other more experience developers out there with my development tasks. For this reason, I continue to use my www.stackoverflow.com bookmark, rather than going to www.stackexchange.com.

Now, I recently posted [How can we connect to an SFTP server from a Windows machine to a Linux SFTP server using a DSA key?](https://superuser.com/questions/314396/how-can-we-connect-to-an-sftp-server-from-a-windows-machine-to-a-linux-sftp-serve) I need to do so programmatically, but I first tried it with a third-party tool and had issues. While it's not a big deal, I was surprised that it got several downvotes for not being a programming question. Apparently, there's another site called Super User where experienced administratos can answer these kinds of questions. I just visited www.stackexhange.com and saw all the other sites.

What do you folks think? Would it be useful to link all the other sites along with their uses from each StackExchange site? I'm sure there are a lot of other people who only go to Stack Overflow and aren't aware of the other sites.

Comment: Nit picking but for sys admin questions you probably want [Server Fault](http://serverfault/faq) rather than [Super User](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the footer of each page.

There you'll find links to all* the other sites in the network.

**UPDATE** Yes, some form of indication of what the site was about would be useful - perhaps as a tooltip when you hover over the link. The one-liner from "Multi-Collider" would work

* Well all the fully fledged sites anyway. The beta sites are all linked in their footers.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something like http://stackexchange.com/sites that I found on the main StackExchange site, that also explains what they are. A normal user who only visits SO (or any other site) wouldn't be aware of what "serverfault" or "superuser" means.

Answer (score 10):

This is already available on the top left corner (MultiCollider).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I saw the down arrow and have used it. I thought it only links to questions. I'd +1 you if I could yet=] Perhaps "all sites" could be labelled "Site List"? What do you think?

Comment: I think all sites is named ok as it is.

Answer (score 4):

All of the other [non-beta] Stack Exchange sites already *are* linked from Stack Overflow. The links are  displayed in the footer at the bottom of every page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something like http://stackexchange.com/sites that I found on the main StackExchange site, that also explains what they are. A normal user who only visits SO (or any other site) wouldn't be aware of what "serverfault" or "superuser" means.

Comment: @HappyCoder4U: And where would we fit all of that?